first homology group and the fundamental group - Hatcher algebraic topology
I have a question regarding Hatcher's theorem 2A.1 (pages 166 to 168) that the first homology group of a path-connected space is the abelianization of the first fundamental group .
The electronic version of the book is made available online by the author so I'm going to provide the Link here for reference :
https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT+.pdf
the last part of the proof (page 167) is showing that if a loop $[f] \in \pi_1 (X)$ , when considered as a 1-cycle, is trivial in $H_1 (X)$ Then $f$ is also trivial in the abelianization of $\pi_1 (X)$ .
$f$ must be the boundary of a 2-chain $\sum n_i\, \sigma_i$, and we can assume each $n_i$ is $\pm 1$, so we can associate to the above 2-chain a  $\Delta \text{-complex}$ $K$ , with identifications coming from the following :
since $$f \; = \; \partial (\sum n_i\, \sigma_i) \; = \; \sum n_i\, \partial \sigma_i \; = \; \sum (-1)^j n_i \tau_{ij}$$   where $\partial \sigma_i=\tau_{i0}-\tau_{i1}+\tau_{i2}$ for singular 1-simplices $\tau_{ij}$, we can group all but one of the of the $\tau_{ij}$'s into pairs for which the coefficients $(-1)^j n_i$ in each pair is $+1$ and $-1$, and the remaining $\tau_{ij}$ must be $f$, and we identify edges corresponding to the paired $\tau_{ij}$'s.
the maps $\sigma_i$ fit together to give a map $\sigma :K \rightarrow X$. by appealing to proposition 0.16 we can deform $\sigma$, staying fixed on the edge corresponding to $f$, so that each vertex maps to the basepoint $x_0$ , thus obtaining a new 2-chain $\sum n_i\, \sigma_i$ with boundary equal to $f$ and all $\tau_{ij}$'s loops based at $x_0$.
since in the abelian group $\pi_1 (X)_{ab}$ we have the formula $[f]=\sum (-1)^j n_i [\tau_{ij}] $ because of the canceling pairs of $\tau_{ij}$'s, we can rewrite the summation as $\sum n_i\, [\partial \sigma_i]$ where as before $[\partial \sigma_i]=[\tau_{i0}]-[\tau_{i1}]+[\tau_{i2}]$.
since $\sigma_i$ gives a nullhomotopy of the composed loops $\tau_{i0}-\tau_{i1}+\tau_{i2}$, we conclude that $[f]=0$ in $\pi_1 (X)_{ab}$.
my problem is with the remarks following the proof : (page 168)

The end of this proof can be illuminated by looking more closely at the geometry.
The complex $K$ is in fact a compact surface with boundary consisting of a single circle
formed by the edge corresponding to f . This is because any pattern of identifications
of pairs of edges of a finite collection of disjoint 2 simplices produces a compact surface
with boundary.We leave it as an exercise for the reader to check that the algebraic formula $f=\partial(\sum \, n_i \, \sigma_i)$
with each $n_i=\pm 1$ implies that $K$ is an orientable surface. The component of K containing the boundary circle is a standard closed orientable surface of some genus g with an open disk removed, by the basic structure theorem for compact orientable surfaces. Giving this surface the cell structure indicated in the figure, it then becomes obvious that f is homotopic to a product of g commutators in $\pi_1(X)$.

can someone please elucidate the above remarks? how can we show that the surface is orientable?
I came across a theorem in John M. Lee's introduction to topological manifolds that I read prior to this book, which explained that by identifying each edge of a polygonal presentation with exactly one other we obtain a 2-manifold, and I suppose when we remove the circle bounded by loop $f$ it produces a boundary.

$K$ is orientable because every face is oriented and on every common edge $e$ of two faces the orientations match up, otherwise $2e$ will show up in the boundary of the 2-chain.

Thank you for your answer.
